# Use binding to format an unbound textbox control?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Is it possible to use the `Binding` class to format/parse an unbound textbox control?

Currently, I was going to inherit from the `Textbox` control, add a new `Format` property and override the `GotFocus` and `Validate` events.

Would using the `Binding` be more suitable or would it not work when the controls are not bound to a datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Binding` class doesn't make sense when you don't use data-binding, unless you yourself want to implement a data-binding-like mechanism for your control.

The binding class is useful because there is a [`CurrencyManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class which uses it and brings it to the circuit, for example when a `ListChange` event fires, it uses the binding class to pull data from data source.

Using a `Binding` or even another custom class is useful only if you have some wire up codes somewhere.

Comment: So in this case is it more suitable to inherit from Textbox and add specific code for formating?

Comment: Inherit if your formatting code is reusable and your control will be used in multiple forms or projects, otherwise handling events is enough.

Comment: Also take a look at [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) for some formatting support.